# Creating a Trigger to update another Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm trying to create a trigger in SQL Server. I'm inserting data into the database through forms that I made in Access. When I create a new record that gets inserted into my `SALESDETAILS` table, I want it to subtract the `quantity` (column) that was just entered in from my `In Stock` (column) in my `PRODUCT` table. `SALESDETAILS` contains a FK from the `PRODUCT` table (`Product_ID`).

This is what I came up with, SQL Server created the trigger, but it doesn't allow any inserts now. After I try to insert something, it says `PRODUCT.[In Stock]` doesn't allow NULLS. `[In Stock]` does have a constraint that doesn't allow NULLS.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Update_Stock] 
ON SALESDETAILS
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    UPDATE PRODUCT
    SET PRODUCT.[In Stock] = (SELECT SALESDETAILS.Quantity - PRODUCT.[In Stock] 
                              FROM SALESDETAILS
                              WHERE SALESDETAILS.Product_ID = PRODUCT.Product_ID)
END
```

I don't think I'm thinking this through correctly, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to subtract the quantity that was just inserted off the `[In Stock]` column in the `PRODUCT` table.

Comment: UPDATE PRODUCT SET [IN STOCK] = [IN STOCK] - inserted.Quantity where Product_id = inserted.product_id   not sure about syntax but shoudllbe something like this

Comment: You need to **reference** the `Inserted` pseudo table in your trigger somehow - that's the "table" that contains the rows that have been inserted - right now, you're updating the whole table every time a single row is inserted - not very efficient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Update_Stock] ON SALESDETAILS FOR INSERT
AS BEGIN
Update p 
set p.stock = p.[stock] - i.quantity
FROM product AS p
INNER JOIN inserted AS i
ON p.id = i.[product_id]
WHERE p.id = i.product_id
END
```

Inserted is the table which lets you get currently inserted values in SALESDETAILS table.

Comment: This worked great! I wasn't aware of the inserted pseudo table available when you create a trigger. Thanks!